# How to get form values in Symfony2 controller

Tags: forms, symfony

I am using a login form on Symfony2 with the following controller code

```
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = new SiteUser();
    $form = $this->createForm(new LoginType(), $user);


    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($request);
        $data = $form->getValues();
        // Need to do something with the data here
    }

    return $this->render('GDSiteBundle::header.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

But I am getting the following warning:

> Warning: array_replace_recursive() [function.array-replace-recursive]: Argument #1 is not an array in \vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Form.php line 593
>   500 Internal Server Error - ErrorException

Can someone help me understand whats incorrect, and how I can fix it? Thanks.

Update:
The twig file is something like this:

```
<div class="form">
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    <form action="{{ path('site_user_login') }}" method="POST" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
        <div class="level1">
            {{ form_row(form.username) }}
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="inscription">{% trans %}Registration{% endtrans %}</a>
        </div>
        <div class="level2">
            {{ form_row(form.pwd_hash) }}
            <div class="forget_pass"><a href="#" id="frgt">{% trans %}Forgot Password ?{% endtrans %}</a></div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="submit" name="login" value/>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the function in the Form's Type

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('username', 'text', array('label' => 'Username : '));
    $builder->add('pwd_hash','password', array('label' => 'Password : '));
}
```

Here is the route:

```
site_user_login:
    pattern: /{_locale}/login
    defaults: {_controller: GDSiteBundle:SiteUser:login}
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Simply :

```
$data = $form->getData();
```

Comment: Nice Answer - RE: below answers. Symfony often allows for many ways to get similar results. It's always good to research "Best Practices" when looking for SF solutions.

Comment: For new versions: $data = $form->all();

Answer (score 99):

None of the above worked for me. This works for me:

```
$username = $form["username"]->getData();
$password = $form["password"]->getData();
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hmmm strange, i got it working with $request->request->get('username'); Did you pass the request object as a parameter to the action? And you need to include the Request Class too in the above.

Answer (score 61):

In Symfony 2 ( to be more specific, the 2.3 version ) you can get a data of an field by

```
$var = $form->get('yourformfieldname')->getData();
```

or you can get all data sent

```
$data = $form->getData();
```

where '$data' is an array containing your form fields' values.

Answer (score 21):

In Symfony >= 2.3, you can get the value of single fields with:

```
$var = $form->get('yourformfieldname')->getData();
```

On the other hand, you can use:

```
$data = $form->getData();
```

**BUT** this would get you two different things:

- the entity with values populated by the form, if your form have the `data-class` option enabled (so it's binded to an entity); this will **exclude** any field with the `'mapping' => false` option
- otherwise, an array with all the form's fields

Answer (score 19):

If you have extra fields in the form that not defined in Entity , `$form->getData()` doesn't work , one way could be this :

```
$request->get("form")["foo"]
```

Or :

```
$form->get('foo')->getData();
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot.

Comment: if you need the id of the query if it is an object you can execute the following command: $form->get('foo')->getData()->getId();

Comment: Really appreciate your answer, it was really helpful.

Answer (score 8):

To get the data of a specific field,

```
$form->get('fieldName')->getData();
```

Or for all the form data

```
$form->getData();
```

Link to docs: https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/forms.html

Answer (score 6):

In Symfony [forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html), there are two different types of [transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) and three different types of underlying data:
[image]

In any form, the three different types of data are:

- **Model data**

  This is the data in the format used in your application (e.g. an Issue object). If you call `Form::getData()` or `Form::setData()`, you're dealing with the "model" data.
- **Norm Data**

  This is a normalized version of your data and is commonly the same as your "model" data (though not in our example). It's not commonly used directly.
- **View Data**

  This is the format that's used to fill in the form fields themselves. It's also the format in which the user will submit the data. When you call `Form::submit($data)`, the $data is in the "view" data format.

The two different types of transformers help convert to and from each of these types of data:

- **Model transformers**:

  `transform()`: "model data" => "norm data"
  `reverseTransform()`: "norm data" => "model data"
- **View transformers**:

  `transform()`: "norm data" => "view data"
  `reverseTransform()`: "view data" => "norm data"

Which transformer you need depends on your situation.

To use the view transformer, call `addViewTransformer()`.

---

If you want to get all form data:

```
$form->getData();
```

If you are after a specific form field (for example `first_name`):

```
$form->get('first_name')->getData();
```

Comment: Nowadays you can also use `$form->all()` which will retrieve even non-mapped fields.

Answer (score 4):

I got it working by this:

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $username = $request->request->get('username');
    $password = $request->request->get('password');

    // Do something with the post data
}
```

You need to have the Request $request as a parameter in the function too!
Hope this helps.

Comment: if your form is not generating using sf2 form builder then only this will show you form value not other solutions. +1 mate

Answer (score 4):

I think that in order to get the request data, bound and validated by the form object, you must use this command :

```
$form->getViewData();
$form->getClientData(); // Deprecated since version 2.1, to be removed in 2.3.
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. The project I'm working on is in symfony 2.0 and can't be updated.

Answer (score 3):

```
private function getFormDataArray($form)
{
    $data = [];
    foreach ( $form as $key => $value) {
        $data[$key] = $value->getData();
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: If your form have subforms, this code should be like: `$data[$key] = is_object($value->getData()) ? $this->getFormDataArray($value) : $value->getData();`

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Symfony 2 security management, you don't need to get posted values, you only need to manage form template (see [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form)).

If you aren't using Symfony 2 security management, I advise you strongly to use it. If you don't want to or if you can't, can you give us the `LoginType`'s sources ?

Comment: Thanks @BlackCharly I am beginning to read the documentation. I have also updated the code to give the reader complete clarity with the same. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

For not mapped form fields I use $form->get('inputName')->getViewData();

Answer (score 1):

If Symfony 4 or 5, juste use this code (Where name is the name of your field):

```
$request->request->get('name');
```